# What is the best practice to make division return double in C#

Tags: c#

In c# when you want to divide the result of a method such as below, what is the best way to force it to return a double value rather than the default integer.

```
(int)Math.Ceiling((double)(System.DateTime.DaysInMonth(2009, 1) / 7));
```

As you can see I need the division to return a double so I can use the ceiling function.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A division of two `int` numbers returns an `int`, truncating any decimal points. This is generally true for other data types as well: arithmetic operations don't change the type of their operands.

To enforce a certain return type, you must therefore convert the operands appropriately. In your particular case, it's actually sufficient to convert one of the operators to `double`: that way, C# will perform the conversion for the other operand automatically.

You've got the choice: You can explicitly convert either operand. However, since the second operand is a *literal*, it's better just to make that literal the correct type directly.

This can either be done using a type suffix (**`d`** in the case of `double`) or to write a decimal point behind it. The latter way is generally preferred. in your case:

```
(int)Math.Ceiling(System.DateTime.DaysInMonth(2009, 1) / 7.0);
```

Notice that this decimal point notation always yields a *`double`*. To make a `float`, you need to use its type suffix: `7f`.

This behaviour of the fundamental operators is the same for nearly all languages out there, by the way. One notable exception: VB, where the division operator generally yields a `Double`. There's a special integer division operator (`\`) if that conversion is not desired. Another exception concerns C++ in a weird way: the difference between two pointers of the same type is a `ptrdiff_t`. This makes sense but it breaks the schema that an operator always yields the same type as its operands. In particular, subtracting two `unsigned int` does *not* yield a `signed int`.

Comment: Ah, thank you, this was confusing me because I come from vb background and the same line of code was working as expected in vb.net but not c#. I changed the parenthesis to cast the first operand and it worked

Comment: wouldn't using 7d instead of using explicit casting work the same way be less ugly?

Comment: @Daniel, sixlettervariables: You're of course right, I lapsed (although I would *never* use the suffix `D` for doubles, since this is redundant: rather, I'd recommend writing 7.0). However, others have already answered this. I guess we can coexist.

Comment: Hah, didn't realize I put a 'd' there, so I'm with you '7.0'!

Comment: Well guys, you've got your wish. I completely rewrote the entry. I also made it a community wiki.

Answer (score 12):

Change the 7 to a double:

```
(int) Math.Ceiling(System.DateTime.DaysInMonth(2009, 1) / 7.0);
```

Comment: you don't need the double casting anymore

Answer (score 3):

just divide with a literal double:

```
(int)Math.Ceiling((System.DateTime.DaysInMonth(2009, 1) / 7.0))
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you can't force a function to return a different type, so casting the result is your best bet.  Casting the result of the function to a double and then dividing should do the trick.

Comment: Um...what?  I think the question is how to use floating-point division rather than integer division.

Comment: In C#, dividing an int by an int always returns an int.  To use fp division, you have to divide doubles.  Since you can't make the function return a double, you have to cast either the function's return value to a double, or make the divisor a double.

Answer (score 1):

To expand upon Konrad's answer...

Changing 7 to 7.0, 7 to 7D, 7 to 7M all get you the answer you want as well.

Answer (score -1):

For a completely different approach that avoids casting and floating-point math altogether...

```
int result = val1 / val2;
if (val1 % val2 != 0) result++;
```

So, in your case...

```
int numDaysInMonth = System.DateTime.DaysInMonth(2009, 1);
int numWeeksInMonth = numDaysInMonth / 7;
if (numDaysInMonth % numWeeksInMonth != 0) numWeeksInMonth++;
```

This approach is quite verbose, but there might be some special cases where it is preferable. Technically, there should be a slight performance advantage to the modulus approach, but you'll be hard-pressed to measure it.

In your case, I'd stick with the accepted answer :-)